# QSerialPort in QThread

Tags: qt, serial-port, qthread

I was trying to read the serial output from a thread. The Serial port is opened in main program and passed the QSerialPort variable to thread.

Then I called `serial.waitForReadyRead()` function in thread, But its not getting any value from serial port. I confirmed that serial port is sending data by reading the same from main program.

Can anyone knows why this behavior is happening?

Adding the code below:

*mainwindow.h*

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        QSerialPort *serial;
    private slots:
        void onProgressChanged();
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };



    class WorkerThread : public QThread {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            QSerialPort *thread_serial;

            void run() {
                int ret = thread_serial->waitForReadyRead(60000);  //thread is not getting any serial data. 
                                                                   //so it will not emit progressChanged.
                if (ret)
                {
                    qDebug()<<"Data Rate Read done";
                    QByteArray recvData = thread_serial->readAll();
                    qDebug()<<recvData;
                    emit progressChanged();
                }
            }
            // Define signal:
            signals:
            void progressChanged();
    };
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    serial = new QSerialPort(this);

    openSerialPort( );
}

void MainWindow::openSerialPort( )
{
    serial->setPortName("COM 4");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {

        qDebug()<<"Connected";

        WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread();
        workerThread->thread_serial = serial;
        connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(progressChanged()),
                                      SLOT(onProgressChanged()));
        workerThread->start();

    }
}

void MainWindow::onProgressChanged()
{
    qDebug()<<"inside onProgressChanged";
}
```

Comment: You haven't [moved](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) your `QSerialPort` to the worker thread -- so it belongs to the thread on which it was created but you're waiting for updates in the worker thread.  That won't work.  But there shouldn't really be any need for a separate thread here.  Just leave everything on the main thread and connect to the appropriate signals.

Comment: I'm using thread because the GUI getting hanged when it wait for readyRead. Is there any way to do waitForReadyRead in background so that my GUI shouldn't hang

Comment: Connect to the [readyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal.

Comment: can you explain in steps? I didn't understood how to use readyRead()